# Method wont work C# When still called out on main

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a new coder and I don't fully understand coding C# but my method wont work for some reason and I did call it out on main.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BOT();
    }
    
    void BOT()
    {
        Random numberGen = new Random();

        String ID = "A.P.B" + numberGen.Next(50, 1000);
        int serial = numberGen.Next(10000000, 1000000000);
        String PU = "AMD RYZEN" + numberGen.Next(1, 11);
        String model = "PAC" + numberGen.Next(10, 1000);

        Console.WriteLine("Hello, My name or my Combat ID is" + ID);
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if there are any compile errors?

Comment: That's exactly what the OP is getting. A compiler error.

Comment: Make BOT() method static !

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `BOT` is in a `static` method. You either need `BOT` to be `static` or you need to create an instance of the class that contains `BOT` to be able to call it.

```
static void BOT()
{
    Random numberGen = new Random();

    String ID = "A.P.B" + numberGen.Next(50, 1000);
    int serial = numberGen.Next(10000000, 1000000000);
    String PU = "AMD RYZEN" + numberGen.Next(1, 11);
    String model = "PAC" + numberGen.Next(10, 1000);

    Console.WriteLine("Hello, My name or my Combat ID is" + ID);
}
```

When I run it now I get:

```
Hello, My name or my Combat ID isA.P.B188
```